# Ultra-high-precision decimal numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, arbitrary-precision

I'm working on a program that finds fractional approximations of pi. As of right now, the best approximation is 245850922/78256779, which yields 64 decimal spots using the Decimal object built into Python 3. I am looking for a method to store decimal values to arbitrary positions, but I have not found any working methods for Python 3. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting your own precision?  The decimal package does support doing that.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister that sounds like exactly what I need. I've looked through the library and haven't been able to find how to do it though, any chance you know how to?

Comment: See the docs for the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) package.  Short form: `import decimal ; decimal.getcontext().prec = 128` or whatever number you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See at [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) project.

Main page contains example of pi number calc using mpmath lib with depth of 50 digits. At least you can try to set it greater and see what will happens.

Comment: this ended up working, thank you